# training YOLOv7 on CPU provides CUDA error

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, yolo

I am trying to run train a yolov7 model without a gpu. This is currently the command line that I am using on colab.

```
python train_aux.py --workers 1 --device cpu --batch-size 1 --data data/coco.yaml --img 128 128 --cfg /content/yolov7/cfg/training/yolov7-e6e.yaml --weights '' --name yolov7-e6e --hypdata/hyp.scratch.p6.yaml`
```

For some reason I first get an warning

```
warnings.warn('User provided device_type of \'cuda\', but CUDA is not available. Disabling')
```

and then I get the error

```
RuntimeError: No CUDA GPUs are available
```

during the first epoch. I dont understand why it is trying to use cuda when I am running it on CPU. Am I missing some spot that I have to edit in the code to fix this? Here is the [link](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7) to the github that I am using

I have tried to download the cuda library incase that helped using.

```
!pip install cuda-python
```

but it didnt solve the issue.

Comment: Try removing the `--device cpu` param. This works for me when running without a GPU.

Comment: @nithins yep this seems to work for some reason, strange that cpu doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like this issue is due to cuda being hard coded into the model for certain procedures. A more in-depth explanation can be found here [link](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/issues/953).In the meantime removing the  `--device cpu` for some reason fixed it.